# How to set value to JTextField which is uneditable and and should not be considered in validation?

Tags: jtextfield

Hi i want to set the JTextField like this (   )    -    . example (999) 999-9999 like this format and when i validate this format should not be considered and when i press backspace or delete it should not be deleted. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

To make it uneditable you should do:

- (object of JTextField).setEditable(false);

and I am not clear about other two Questions, can you explain it please.

Comment: JTextField should take phone number and it should automatically convert to us format ex:- (###) ###-####   like this.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help you:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Format extends JFrame {
    public JTextArea ja;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Format ft = new Format();
    }

    Format() {
        ja = new JTextArea("Enter Phone Number:");
        ja.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_ENTER) {
                    String st = ja.getText();
                    ja.setText("");
                    char[] ch = st.toCharArray();
                    if(ch.length==10){
                    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            ja.append("(" + ch[i]);
                        } else if (i == 3) {
                            ja.append(")" + " " + ch[i]);
                        } else if (i == 6) {
                            ja.append("-" + ch[i]);
                        } else {
                            ja.append("" + ch[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    ja.setEditable(false);
                }
            }
            }
        });
        add(ja, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for swift response, JTextField should take phone number and it should automatically convert to us format ex:- (###) ###-#### like this and it should not accept more than 10 digit. (111) 111-1111 and if i type less than 10 digit it should accept.

Comment: I think i have already done the first part, for the second you have to ass a simple check, i have edited the code above you can see